# Null pointer exception when I run the runner class after the addition of code for extent reports

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, error-handling, cucumber, testng

```
package Runner;



@CucumberOptions(
                 plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/ExtentReport", "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:"}, 
                 features = {"src\\main\\java\\Feature_PSA" }, 
                 glue = "com.test.Step_def",
                 dryRun = false, monochrome = true
                )
    

public class Runner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
    public static SoftAssertions assertion;
    
    //Added form StackOverflow 
    private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;
    @DataProvider(name="myFeatures")
    public Object[][] getFeatures()
    {
        if(testNGCucumberRunner == null){
            testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
        }
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideFeatures();
    }
    
    


    
    
    
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        assertion = new SoftAssertions();
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());
        ExtentProperties extentProperties = ExtentProperties.INSTANCE;
        extentProperties.setReportPath("cucumber-reports/" + timeStamp.replace(":", "_").replace(".", "_") + ".html");
        
    }
    
    
    @AfterClass
    public static void writeExtentReport() {
        // ExtentReports extentReports = new ExtentReports();
        // ExtentSparkReporter sparkReporter = new
        // ExtentSparkReporter("C:\\Users\\ms50\\OneDrive - Capgemini\\Desktop\\Office
        // stuff\\Automation testing\\PSA\\Code\\PSA_Test\\target\\ExtentReport");
        // extentReports.attachReporter(sparkReporter);
        // extentReports.flush();

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());
        String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File(workingDir + "\\config\\extent-config.xml"));
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("Automation Done By: ", "Monish");
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("Time Zone", System.getProperty("user.timezone"));
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("Time: ", timeStamp);
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("Machine", "Windows 10" + " " + "64 Bit");
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("Java Version", "1.8");
        assertion.assertAll();

    }

}
```

The code when run throws the following error:

[Error] java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.provideFeatures()" because "this.testNGCucumberRunner" is null

and

FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass cucumber. api-testng. Abstract Test NG Cucumber Tests. set Up Class
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/formatter/Reporter

I was able to run the code and execute it properly before i added code for extent reports.

Comment: Not exactly your problem, but your problem has the same solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/67416321/3945473